# Possible reasons Distribution of durations is tri-modal

Tags: iis-7.5, asp.net, performance-tuning

Below is the distribution graph of durations from a single page of an asp.net webforms application. As you can see there is a cluster of response times in the 250ms range, there is a cluster in the 1400ms range and there is a cluster in the 4000ms range. This surprised me. Maybe my high school math teacher mislead me, but I was expected something approximating a normal distribution.

I'm curious if other's have seen this pattern and what the cause could be.

My first thought was perhaps the page has conditional logic that makes addition expensive database calls in certain situations, but that isn't the case. There are 4 database calls in every case. And none of the database calls is expensive.

[image: Response Times extracted from application insights]

Comment: Quite a few latency distributions are multimodal. There can be distinct fast and slow paths, the root causes of which are not obvious. Keep profiling.  http://www.brendangregg.com/HeatMaps/latency.html